# how i can suspend child process and reset it

Tags: c, fork, wait, execve

I am creating a child process with fork in my shell, and assigned this child process to execute a cmd, for example : "ls -lR /", with 'execve()' like u see in my code, when i receive SIGTSTP, i want to stop this child process with `kill(child_process, SIGTSTP)`, and when you type "fg" command i have to reset this child runing with `kill(child_process, SIGCONT)`, problem is `wait(&status)` after i receive SIGTSTP never return is still waiting child to end,
-- so how i can do that ??

```
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int child_pid;
int parn_pid;

void    func1(int sig)
{
    kill(child_pid, SIGTSTP);
}

int main()
{
    int sig;
    int status;
    char *argv[] = {"ls", "-lR", "/", NULL};

    signal(SIGTSTP, func1);
    child_pid = fork();
    if (child_pid == 0)
    {
        child_pid = getpid();
        execve("/bin/ls", argv, NULL);
        exit (1);
    }
    else
    {
        parn_pid = getpid();
        waitpid(child_pid, &status, WUNTRACED);
        printf("\nsuspended\n");
        if (WIFSTOPPED(status))
        {
            sleep(2);
            kill(child_pid, SIGCONT);
            wait(&status);
        }
    }
    return (0);
}
```

Comment: Turn on your compiler warnings: `warning: result of comparison of constant 18 with boolean expression is always false [-Wtautological-constant-out-of-range-compare]
            if (WIFSIGNALED(status) == SIGTSTP)`

Comment: You are using WIFSIGNALED incorrectly, and therefore never sending SIGCONT.

Comment: solved, but printf never put "\nsuspended\n" this mean wait is still waiting child to end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `waitpid()` rather than `wait()`.  Using `wait()` will wait for a child process to be **terminated**, which means the processes must have exited, for example from SIGKILL or SIGSEGV.  You are trying to wait for the process to be **stopped**, which is not the same thing.  Stopping a process just pauses it and it allows it to be continued later.  It doesn't exit.

You need to use the `WUNTRACED` flag with `waitpid()` to wait for a child processes to be terminated *or stopped*.  Such as `waitpid(child_pid, &status, WUNTRACED)` or `waitpid(-1, &status, WUNTRACED)`.

There is another flaw related to this.  `WIFSIGNALLED()` and `WTERMSIG()` also apply only to a processing which was terminated by a signal.  You should instead use `WIFSTOPPED()` and `WSTOPSIG()` to detect if the child was stopped.

Also note:

- `SIGSTOP` can also stop a processes.
- You may receive a `SIGTSTP` anytime after the signal handler is set, which could be before `child_pid` is assigned a value.
- `wait()` and friends can return -1 with `errno` set to `EINTR` if your processes is interrupted by a signal.

Comment: your answer was very helpful it solved my problem, thanks for sharing this information.